# iOS Metal: Jaggies Anit-aliasing

Tags: ios, objective-c, opengl-es, metal, antialiasing

I was trying to draw a half circle with renderEncoder's drawIndexedPrimitives

```
[renderEncoder setVertexBuffer:self.vertexBuffer offset:0 atIndex:0];

[renderEncoder drawIndexedPrimitives:MTLPrimitiveTypeTriangleStrip
                              indexCount:self.indexCount
                               indexType:MTLIndexTypeUInt16
                             indexBuffer:self.indicesBuffer
                       indexBufferOffset:0];
```

where the vertexBuffer and indicesBuffer for the circle were created by calculation

```
int segments = 10;


float vertices02[ (segments +1)* (3+4)];
vertices02[0] = centerX;
vertices02[1] = centerY;
vertices02[2] = 0;

//3, 4, 5, 6 are RGBA
vertices02[3] = 1.0;
vertices02[4] = 0;
vertices02[5] = 0.0;
vertices02[6] = 1.0;    

uint16_t indices[(segments -1)*3];

for (int i = 1; i <= segments ; i++){
    float degree = (i -1) * (endDegree - startDegree)/ (segments -1) + startDegree;

    vertices02[i*7] = (centerX + cos([self degreesToRadians:degree])*radius);
    vertices02[i*7 +1] = (centerY +  sin([self degreesToRadians:degree])*radius);
    vertices02[i*7 +2] = 0;

    vertices02[i*7 +3] = 1.0;
    vertices02[i*7 +4] = 0;
    vertices02[i*7 +5] = 0.0;
    vertices02[i*7 +6] = 1.0;

    if (i < segments){
        indices[(i-1)*3 + 0] = 0;
        indices[(i-1)*3 + 1] = i;
        indices[(i-1)*3 + 2] = i+1;
    }
}
```

So I am combining 9 Triangle to form a 180 degree circle.

Then create vertexBuffer and indicesBuffer

```
self.vertexBuffer = [device newBufferWithBytes:vertexArrayPtr
                                            length:vertexDataSize
                                           options:MTLResourceOptionCPUCacheModeDefault];
self.indicesBuffer = [device newBufferWithBytes:indexArrayPtr
                                             length:indicesDataSize 
                                            options:MTLResourceOptionCPUCacheModeDefault];
```

The result is like this:

[image: Half Circle by Metal]

I believe this is Anti-Aliasing problem from Metal of iOS. I used to create half circle in OpenGL using same technique but the edges was much smoother.

Any suggestions to tackle the problem?

---

Suggested by warrenm, I should set the CAMetalLayer's drawableSize equals screenSize x scale. There are improvements:

[image]

---

Another Suggestion by warrenm, using MTKView and setting sampleCount = 4 solved the problem:
[image]

Comment: It looks like the drawable size of your Metal layer is significantly smaller than the pixel dimensions of your view. If you’re using `CAMetalLayer` directly, have you tried setting its `drawableSize` property to the view size multiplied by the screen’s scale?

Comment: You could also enable MSAA by setting the `sampleCount` of your render pipeline to 4, and rendering into/resolving from a suitably-sized render target, but I think you’ll see significant improvements by matching the render target size to the pixel dimensions of the view, even without resorting to MSAA.

Comment: @warrenm thanks for your help. Yes, I've been using CAMetalLayer, and there's significant improvement after setting the drawableSize as you mentioned. I wanted to try to set the pipelineDescriptor's sampleCount to 4, but crashes when I try to run, I think I'll need MTKView to match the sampleCount between the renderPipeline and renderTarget?

Comment: That's right; the sample count of the view needs to match the sample count of the render pipeline state. If you're using `MTKView`, it will create the appropriate multisampled textures for you; you simply need to set the sample count.

Comment: @warrenm, thanks for your help. Using MTKView and setting sampleCount fixed the problem. Would you like to post your comment as an answer for me to accept?

Comment: Happy this worked for you. I've added an answer before that lays out some more details about what's happening behind the scenes, in the hope that it helps those visiting this question in the future.

Comment: @warrenm thanks for the detailed explanation, it gives me more ideas about what's happening behind the scene. I believe your answer will be useful for somebody in the future who come across similar problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of things to consider here. First, you need to ensure that (when possible) the size of the grid you're rasterizing to matches the resolution of the display it will be viewed on. Second, you might need to use subpixel techniques to eke out additional smoothness, since raster techniques tend to undersample continuous functions.

In Metal, the way we match the rendered image size to the display is by ensuring that the *drawable size* of the Metal layer matches the *pixel dimensions* it will occupy on the screen. When using `CAMetalLayer` directly, the default behavior is for the drawable size of the layer to be the size of the layer's bounds multiplied by the layer's `contentsScale` property. Setting the latter to the `scale` of the `UIScreen` onto which the layer is composited will match the layer's dimensions to the screen's pixels (ignoring other transformations that might be applied to the layer or its view hierarchy).

When using `MTKView`, the `autoResizeDrawable` property determines whether the view automatically manages its layer's drawable size. This is the default behavior, but if you set this property to `NO`, you can manually set the drawable size to something else (e.g., use adaptive resolution rendering when fragment-bound).

In order to sample more finely, we have our choice among any number of antialiasing techniques, but perhaps the easiest of these is multisampled antialiasing (MSAA), a hardware feature that—as the name suggests—takes multiple samples for each pixel along the edges of primitives, in order to reduce the jagged effects of aliasing.

In Metal, using MSAA requires setting multisampling state (i.e., the sample count) on both the render pipeline state and the textures used for rendering. MSAA is a two-step process, where a render target that can hold the data for multiple fragments per pixel is rendered to, then a *resolve* step combines these samples into the final color for each pixel. When using `CAMetalLayer` (or drawing off-screen), you must create a texture of type `MTLTextureType2DMultisample` for each active color/depth attachment. These textures are configured as the `texture` property of their respective color/depth attachments, and the `resolveTexture` property is set to a texture of type `MTLTextureType2D`, into which the MSAA targets are resolved.

When using `MTKView`, simply setting the `sampleCount` on the view to match the `sampleCount` of the render pipeline descriptor is sufficient to get MetalKit to create and manage the appropriate resources. By default, the render pass descriptors you receive from a view will have an internally-managed MSAA color target set as the primary color attachment, and the current drawable's texture set as the resolve texture of that attachment. In this way, enabling MSAA with MetalKit only requires a couple of lines of code.